Block matrix of arbitrary dimensions
I have a block matrix that has a general form as sketched below:

(excuse my handwriting). The dimension of each individual matrix is indicated. The 0_{ixj} are zero matrices of dimension i x j.
My issue is that I'm not sure how to define this matrix generally in Mathematica. If it were just the part boxed off in green, I would do as follows:
m = ConstantArray[\[Mu],{14,14}]//MatrixForm;
t = ConstantArray[\[Tau],{14,14}]//MatrixForm; (*just to have the matrices defined*)
j = 10; (*an example of the dimension of the block matrix*)
offdiagonal1 = ConstantArray[0,{j,j}]; (offdiagonal1[[#+1,#]]=1)&/@Range[1,j-1];
offdiagonal2 = Transpose[offdiagonal1];
mymatrix = KroneckerProduct[offdiagonal1,t] + KroneckerProduct[offdiagonal2,ConjugateTranspose[t]] + KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[j],m];

This is maybe not the most elegant way of doing it. If H was a block matrix consisting of consisting of 9 matrices (i.e. H only consists of the matrices written explicitly), I would create a matrix with the A, B, M and T matrices as elements and use ArrayFlatten, but I'm not sure how to generalize this to arbitrary dimensions.

Is this what you want?
a = ( {
    {a11, a12},
    {a21, a22}
   } );
b = ( {
    {b11, b12},
    {b21, b22},
    {b31, b32},
    {b41, b42}
   } );
m = ConstantArray[\[Mu], {4, 4}];
t = ConstantArray[\[Tau], {4, 4}];
h = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
h[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]] = a;
h[[3 ;; 6, 1 ;; 2]] = b;
h[[1 ;; 2, 3 ;; 6]] = ConjugateTranspose[b];
h[[3 ;; 6, 3 ;; 6]] = h[[7 ;; 10, 7 ;; 10]] = m;
h[[7 ;; 10, 3 ;; 6]] = t;
h[[3 ;; 6, 7 ;; 10]] = ConjugateTranspose[t];
MatrixForm[h]


